# iOS: How to Retrieve Created At / Updated At Timestamp from Firebase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

When I create a new value on Firebase does it automatically create a createdAt and updatedAt field or am I supposed to handle that on my own? I've noticed there's a constants `kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp` which is essentially a dictionary. How can I use that to retrieve that value after creating my object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value by listening to the location:

```
Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"<my-firebase-app>/timestamp"];

// listen for update
[ref observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
  NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value);
}];

// save timestamp
[ref setValue: kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp];
```

Comment: Woah. I feel dumb. So easy. Thanks David!

Comment: No need to feel dumb! Async data has a learning curve, and you're well on your way to mastering it :)